# export chart to excel using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tried for Gridview:

```
private void ExportToExcel() {

    try {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=OverallReport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            dgvTrendChart.AllowPaging = false;
            this.SearchOverallList();

            dgvTrendChart.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach(TableCell cell in dgvTrendChart.HeaderRow.Cells) {
                cell.BackColor = dgvTrendChart.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }

            for (int rowIndex = dgvTrendChart.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--) {
                GridViewRow row = dgvTrendChart.Rows[rowIndex];
                GridViewRow previousRow = dgvTrendChart.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) {
                    if (i != 3) {
                        if (row.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text) {
                            row.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 :
                                previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                            previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                            row.Cells[i].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                            row.Cells[i].VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dgvTrendChart.RenderControl(hw);

            string style = @ "<style>.textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    } catch {
        //throw new Exception("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Here i have tried exporting gridview into excel.It is working fine.But my question is how to export a line chart into excel sheet.